# Keep pseudo element on same line as parent <a> tag

Tags: css

I have this link:

```
<a href="#">Laboris chuck pastrami ribeye nisi</a>
```

I'm adding an arrow using a pseudo element:

```
a::after {
    content: ">";
    margin-left: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But how can I prevent the pseuto element to break into a new line alone? I want to keep the arrow attached to the last word at all times. See Fiddle.
If I remove `display: inline-block;` from the `::after`, it seems to work and the arrow breaks with the last word, but then the pseudo element is also underlined like the parent. I don't want that.

How can I get around this? Any ideas?

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qga5us4L/).

[image: What I have]

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.box` has a fixed width therefore your `:after` content is forced to wrap. You can prevent this by setting its position as absolute;

```css
a::after {
content: ">";
margin-left: 7px;
display: inline-block;
position:absolute; /* <-- position it absolutely */
}

.box {
  width: 225px;
  border:1px dotted red; /* <-- added to illustrate my point */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">Laboris chuck pastrami ribeye nisi</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Further to your clarification. If your `:after` is inline it is rendered the same as if you had just appended `>` at the end of the link (ie without using a pseudo element). This is why it is positioned as you expect when your remove `display:inline-block` and is the reason why it also gets the underline. What you want cannot be done with the code you have. You would need to add some more mark-up to differentiate the bits you do want underlined from that which you do not. For example, by wrapping the bit you want underlined in a `span`:

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}
a>span {text-decoration:underline;}

a::after {
content: ">";
margin-left: 7px;
display: inline;
}

.box {
  width: 225px;
  border:1px dotted red; /* <-- added to illustrate my point */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#"><span>Laboris chuck pastrami ribeye nisi</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. I want the last word to break along with the arrow. Not just the arrow. The width of the box is just for illustration.

Comment: Oh. Your question does not make that clear. Perhaps a picture illustrating what you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because of your width in your "box" div. remove the width and it'll work just like the below:

[ edited accordingly as per question's edit]

```css
span::after {
    content: ">";
    margin-left: 7px;
    display: inline-block;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box {
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">Laboris chuck pastrami ribeye <span>nisi</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. I want the last word to break along with the arrow. Not just the arrow. The width of the box is just for illustration.

Comment: then you probably need to wrap your last word in a `span` tag and then make the `span` display `inline-block`. this will remove the underline from the span. so you need to add `text-decoration: underline` in the span tag.

I edited my answer accordingly. you can check that

[EDIT: add the pseudo `after` in the `span` tag instead of `a`]

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your solution works, but I would prefer a more dynamic and css-only solution.